# Logical arrays as indices to arrays to convert elements to zero in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, boolean

I am trying to convert some elements of a matrix to zeros depending on a logical array.

Suppose we have a random `5 x 5` matrix:

```
b =

0.0344    0.1869    0.7547    0.1190    0.2238
0.4387    0.4898    0.2760    0.4984    0.7513
0.3816    0.4456    0.6797    0.9597    0.2551
0.7655    0.6463    0.6551    0.3404    0.5060
0.7952    0.7094    0.1626    0.5853    0.6991
```

And I have an array of zeros and ones with the same dimension:

```
a =

 0     1     1     0     0
 1     0     1     1     0
 1     1     0     1     1
 0     1     1     0     1
 0     0     1     1     0
```

Doing `a(logical(b))` gives me the elements I am looking for, but in a vector form:

```
ans =

0.4387
0.3816
0.1869
0.4456
0.6463
0.7547
0.2760
0.6551
0.1626
0.4984
0.9597
0.5853
0.2551
0.5060
```

How can I get the following matrix instead?

```
0         0.1869    0.7547    0         0
0.4387    0         0.2760    0.4984    0.7513
0.3816    0.4456    0         0.9597    0.2551
0         0.6463    0.6551    0         0.5060
0         0         0.1626    0.5853    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that there was an answer in another question.

Setting `b(~logical(a)) = 0` works.

(Just keeping this here because the question is phrased a bit differently.)

Comment: You can do `b(a == 0) = 0;` to be even shorter.  I would say this more expressly states what you want to do rather than using `~logical(a)`.

Comment: You could also do an element-wise multiply `.*`.